# I am trying to pass variables from a form to a url works in firefox and explorer but will not work in chrome

Tags: html

here is the site https://rivervalleyinn.squarespace.com/
it will not pass the date or other info in chrome but it works great in firefox and explorer I am trying to pass two dates and room info to a booking site the dates and other info do not appear to pass in chrome to the url thanks for the help in advance

```
 <head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
  </script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="step1" mthod="post"   ID="Form1" action="http://www.directinn.com/014282/step2.html"> 
Check in Date <input id="datepicker" type=Date name=CheckIn><br>
Check out Date<input id="datepicker" type=Date name=CheckOut><br>
<table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" border="0" ID="Table2" class="text4">
 <tr id="HEADER">
  <td width="10"></td><td width="60"><strong>Rooms:</strong></td><td width="70">&nbsp;</td><td width="70"><strong>Adults: </strong></td><td width="70">&nbsp;</td><td width="70"><strong>Children: </strong></td> </tr>
 <tr id="ROOM1">
  <td width="10">&nbsp;</td><td width="60">
   <select style="WIDTH: 50px" onchange="ShowRoom();(document.step1.RoomCnt.value);" name="RoomCnt" size="1"><OPTION value="1" selected>1</OPTION><OPTION value="2">2</OPTION><OPTION value="3">3</OPTION></select>  </td>
  <td width="70" align="center" id="ROOM1TAG">Room 1</td>  <td width="70">
   <select style="WIDTH: 50px" name="Guest1" size="1">
   <OPTION value="1">1</OPTION><OPTION value="2" selected>2</OPTION><OPTION value="3">3</OPTION><OPTION value="4">4</OPTION><OPTION value="5">5</OPTION>  </select></td>       
  <td width="70">&nbsp;</td><td width="70"><select style="WIDTH: 50px" name="Child1" size="1"><OPTION value="0" selected>0</OPTION><OPTION value="1">1</OPTION><OPTION value="2">2</OPTION><OPTION value="3">3</OPTION><OPTION value="4">4</OPTION><OPTION value="5">5</OPTION></select> </td>
</tr>
<tr id="ROOM2ON" >
 <td width="10">&nbsp;</td><td width="60">
  <td width="70" align="center">Room 2</td>  <td width="70">
   <select style="WIDTH: 50px" name="Guest2" ID="A2" size="1"><OPTION value="1">1</OPTION><OPTION value="2" selected>2</OPTION><OPTION value="3">3</OPTION><OPTION value="4">4</OPTION><OPTION value="5">5</OPTION>  </select> 
 </td>
 <td width="70">&nbsp;</td><td width="70"><select style="WIDTH: 50px" name="Child2" size="1"><OPTION value="0" selected>0</OPTION><OPTION value="1">1</OPTION><OPTION value="2">2</OPTION><OPTION value="3">3</OPTION><OPTION value="4">4</OPTION><OPTION value="5">5</OPTION></select></tr>
<tr id="ROOM3ON">
 <td width="10">&nbsp;</td><td width="60">
  <td width="70" align="center">Room 3</td> 
 <td width="70">
 <select style="WIDTH: 50px" name="Guest3" ID="A3" size="1"><OPTION value="1">1</OPTION><OPTION value="2" selected>2</OPTION><OPTION value="3">3</OPTION><OPTION value="4">4</OPTION><OPTION value="5">5</OPTION></select> 
</td> 
 <td width="70">&nbsp;</td><td width="70"><select style="WIDTH: 50px" name="Child3" size="1"><OPTION value="0" selected>0</OPTION><OPTION value="1">1</OPTION><OPTION value="2">2</OPTION><OPTION value="3">3</OPTION><OPTION value="4">4</OPTION><OPTION value="5">5</OPTION></select></tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">    
function ShowRoom(){
 var tbl=document.getElementById("Table2");
 tbl.style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("HEADER").style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("ROOM1").style.display="block";
 if (document.step1.RoomCnt.value == 1){
  document.getElementById("ROOM1TAG").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("ROOM2ON").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("ROOM3ON").style.display="none";
 } else if (document.step1.RoomCnt.value == 2) {
  document.getElementById("ROOM1TAG").innerHTML="Room 1";
  document.getElementById("ROOM2ON").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("ROOM3ON").style.display="none";
 }
 else if (document.step1.RoomCnt.value == 3){
  document.getElementById("ROOM1TAG").innerHTML="Room 1";
  document.getElementById("ROOM2ON").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("ROOM3ON").style.display="block";
 }
}
ShowRoom();
</script></td>


<input type=submit value=Submit></form>

    </body>
```

Comment: Chrome has native input type="Date" datepicker functionality -- perhaps adding jQuery's on top is interfering with the form values?

Comment: have any ideas how to get around it

Comment: There's a snippet that can detect this feature at the bottom of the page here: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome

Comment: so I pulled the java script out of the header and t it still will not work I have the java script code in https://rivervalleyinn.squarespace.com/ page  and not on page https://rivervalleyinn.squarespace.com/test/

Comment: oh my god cory I got it you were correct that page link you send me was a god send I was banging my head against the wall all it was type=text on date picker the rest was good appears to work in all browsers now thanks so much

Comment: Glad you got it resolved. I wrote an answer incorporating my comments and your response.

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering a conflict between Chrome's native date picker for `<input type="date">` and the normal target of jQuery's date picker, `<input type="text">`.

My suggestion would be incorporate a quick feature-test for browser's that handle `<input type="date">` on their own, and use it to decide whether you need to bind the jQuery date picker widget.

In the following example I have borrowed a date-input-feature-test implementation from [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome). This is what your new code might look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var isDateInputSupported = function() {
        var elem = document.createElement('input');
        elem.setAttribute('type','date');
        elem.value = 'foo';
        return (elem.type == 'date' && elem.value != 'foo');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (!isDateInputSupported()) {
            $("#datepicker, #datepicker1").datepicker();
        }
    });

</script>
```